# Maclaurin series for sin(x) representation

Tags: taylor-expansion

The Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$ is:

$$ \sin(x) =  x - \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{x^5}{5!} - \dfrac{x^7}{7!} ... $$

Which according to wikipedia is:

$$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}$$

I however don't understand why this notation is correct at all. It only seems to work if you consider that $x$ is the zeroth term. Why is it the zeroth term?

Comment: They are the same. what's the problem? :)

Comment: Because that's what the notation says? The summation starts at $n = 0$.

Comment: If you're talking about finding the Maclaurin series from the formal definition, technically it's not the zeroth term (which would be $\frac{\sin(0)}{0!}x^0$) - the zeroth term is 0 since $\sin(0)=0$, so the $x^0$ term can be neglected.

Comment: when $n=0$  you get $(-1)^0=1$ and $(2\times 0+1)!=1$ and $x^{2\times 0+1}=x$.  Does that explain it?

Comment: You may also write $$ \sum_{k=42}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k-83)!}x^{2k-83}$$

Comment: The initial index $ \ n = 0 \ $ is chosen for the convenience of writing the expression for the general term in a particular way. There is no requirement to start from there: one could as easily write $ \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)!} x^{2n-1} . $ It is only colloquial to refer to terms as "zeroth", "first", etc. and these are not always used consistently.  It really makes more sense to point to the form of the general term and describe terms in the series by index values.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by the zeroth term? Do you mean the term given by $n = 0$? In this case simple evaluation shows this term to be $$\frac{(-1)^{0}}{(2(0)+1)!}x^{2(0)+1} = \frac{1}{1!}x^{1} = x$$

If, however, you are wondering why the first non-zero term of the Maclaurin series is $0$, then it is as simple as observing the following:

Let $f(x) = \sin(x)$.

Then $f'(x) = \cos(x)$

... $f''(x) = -\sin(x)$

... $f'''(x) = -\cos(x)$

... $f^{(4)}(x) = \sin(x)$

and so on. It is easy to note that for $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for $k$ even, since for $k$ even, $f^{(k)}(x) = c\sin x$, where $c$ is $1$ or $-1$, and $\sin(0) = 0$.

On the other hand, this gives us an expression for odd $k$. Writing $k$ odd as $2n+1$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $f^{(2n+1)}(x) = (-1)^{n}\cos(x)$, and so $f^{(2n+1)}(0) = (-1)^{n}\cos(0) = (-1)^{n}$. The rest of the expression given by wikipedia, then, follows from the definition of a Maclaurin series.

Comment: Why do you consider $x$ to be the zeroth term. Shouldn't it be the first term?

Comment: It seems to me that you're troubled by convention. The constant term of this series is $0$ - if that's what you want to call the zeroth term, then it's there, you just don't write it. Hence, the first nonzero term is $x$. Call it however you want it, just be precise and consistent. The series only has nonzero odd powers of $x$ in it (as per the above explanation), and so it's written as you see it with the index starting at 0 but the first nonzero term as $x$.

Comment: Maybe Taylor is thinking of his Taylor series in terms of exponents only, so let me write it this way: $$\sin x = \sum_{k \text{ odd}} (-1)^{(k-1)/2}\frac {x^k}{k!}\,.$$ Since every odd number can be written in the form $k=2n+1$, we end up at the same place.